# calling servlet on jsp page button click

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to call a servlet controller on JSP button click.I cannot use form submit button as I have other operations on it. Apart from an AJAX call is there any other way to call a servlet ? I wanted to know, is there any option like the below code

```
<a href="goToServlet?param1=value1&param2=value2">Go to servlet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

A Servlet's **doGet method** is mapped onto a specific URL which can be accessed directly with the URL. This is **not possible with a doPost** method.

For example:

If i have a servlet called `TestServlet` which has a url-pattern `testme`,

then i can access this servlet with an achor tag like this:

```
<a href="/testme?param1=cool&param2=nice">Go to servlet</a>
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testme</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**TestServlet doGet method**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

          String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
          String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");



        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("anotherPage.jsp");    

        rd.forward(request,response);  
    }

}
```